# Can I have more workers dedicated to an specific task in Python? Parallelization of 2 tasks with different time consuming

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have to download a list of files from a slow ftp server, each downloading lasts around 40s.

For each of this files I have to process to tasks:
'A' lasts around 30-40s
'a' lasts less than 10s

Each time a download is finished I'm launching processes 'A' and 'a' in parallel using multiprocessing library but, because sometimes process 'A' lasts the same time as the downloading, I can't assure that I will finish the job ('A'+'a') before the next file of the list comes.

I was wondering if there's any way that I could give more workers to task 'A' to speed it up so the complete job can be done between downloads.
I'm using a Raspi 4 with 4 cores so I was thinking 1 core for downloading, 1 core for task 'a' and 2 cores for task 'A'.

Is this possible? Any ideas are welcome

Comment: what have you tried, and where did you get stuck? Generally in python things that are I/O bound like downloading over the network can be punted to a thread, but CPU intensive tasks need a parallel process (`threading`, and `multiprocessing` libraries are standard with any new-ish version of python)

Comment: Task `A` has to be such that it can be divided into two subtasks to take advantage of two cores.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!
Aaron: I'm downloading the files  in the forefront and (after first download finishes) processing in the "background" using two parallel process using multiprocessing.Process and joining (Process.join())them before the next download start.
Booboo: I'm figuring out If I can divide A in 2 independent subtasks, possibly the only answer to my question